# NASM - Create labels in a %rep section

Tags: label, nasm, rep

Bonjour

Here is what I expect :

```
irq_wrapper_0:         ; The code of each irq_wrapper is similar and not shown
irq_wrapper_1:
irq_wrapper_2:  
irq_wrapper_3:

...

irq_wrapper_array:
  dd irq_wrapper_0
  dd irq_wrapper_1
  dd irq_wrapper_2
  dd irq_wrapper_3
```

Could you tell me where I'm wrong and why I can't write the folowing :

```
%define MyMacro(id) irq_wrapper_ +% id  

%assign id 0
%rep 4               
  MyMacro(id) :     
  %assign id id+1
%endrep

...

irq_wrapper_array: 
%assign id 0
%rep 4               
  dd MyMacro(id)    
  %assign id id+1
%endrep
```

- Obviously the code above is an excerpt.
- I have more than 4 vectors
- I would like to use the preprocessor to avoid to manual unfolding which seems error prône

Regards, 40tude

Comment: Sorry guys, I must be tired. It is almost 3AM here.
The solution is : replace "+%" with "%+" in the macro and it works.
Regards